# Máquinas de Inferência Open Source

Tags: inteligência-artificial

Nem sei se aqui é o melhor lugar pra essa pergunta, mas gostaria de saber se existem máquinas de inferências Open Source, se possível em Java ou C# (embora eu nem saiba se essas duas linguagens são mesmo usadas pra esse tipo de AI).

Preciso de uma máquina de inferência que trabalhe numa situação como a seguinte: imagine um software onde um paciente responde perguntas pre-determinadas e a partir disso, o software decide quais as possíveis doenças que o paciente pode ter. Como é algo que eu (nem meus amigos) nunca fizemos antes, é difícil ter certeza quando de encontra algo. Até agora, encontramos duas, que creio ser o que procuramos: Jena e Infer.net. Mas qualquer ajuda é muito bem-vinda.

Comment: Vai montar um sistema especialista?

Comment: A ideia é parecida com essa da medicina, sabe?

Comment: Sim, existem. Leia sobre o [CLIPSNET](https://clips.codeplex.com/) ou o [CLIPSJNI](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/CLIPSJNIBeta.html), que são integrações em C# e Java do famoso [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/). Ou procure por "Java Rule Engine", por exemplo. Você encontrará coisas bacanas como o [Drools](http://www.drools.org/) ou o [EasyRules](http://www.easyrules.org/). De todas as formas, sua pergunta não está no escopo do site. Se não fez ainda, leia [ask].

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque é uma pergunta do tipo lista.

Comment: Veja o [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html).